# GoogleMap Android share location issue on Samsung

Tags: android, google-maps, share, intentfilter, samsung

My app is composed by 2 Activities:

1. Splash
2. Main

Splash intent filters are:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Launch modes are:
Splash: not defined
Main: singleTask

Follow the steps below:

1. My App is closed
2. Open GoogleMap
3. Select a location on the chart
4. Tap on share
5. Select my App

The app is opened as expected and the flow (coming from log added) is:

1. Splash.onCreate
2. Splash.onResume
3. Splash.onPause
4. Main.onCreate
5. Main.onResume
6. Splash.onDestroy

Now put the app in background and reopen Google Map and share a new location using my App.
The app is opened as expected but the flow is:

1. Main.onResume

Nothing more.

The behaviour changes if my App is opened the first time by the User and after that the User starts to interact with Google Map Share feature. Please find below the flow about the latest scenario:

1. Splash.onCreate
2. Splash.onResume
3. Splash.onPause
4. Main.onNewIntent
5. Main.onResume
6. Splash.onDestroy

I cannot change the activities launch flags.

Have you any idea about why I have only onResume in the flow?

Thanks.